# Is a Windows Timer as accurate as Sleep()?

Tags: c, winapi

`Sleep()` is very accurate, so for example if I want to sleep for 10 hours:

```
Sleep(36000000); // sleep for 10 hours
```

My thread will wait for exactly 10 hours (plus the time that Windows needs to wake up my thread, which is negligible).

However, since `Sleep()` will block my UI thread, I which to use Windows Timers instead. So is a Windows Timer as accurate as `Sleep()`? that is, will it wait for exactly 10 hours (plus the time it needs for my Window Procedure to receive the `WM_TIMER` message)?

Comment: I think `sleep()` would also use the OS timer only to calculate `10 hours`.

Comment: Use a scheduled task

Comment: @Haris What do you mean "**only** to calculate 10 hours", will it use something else if it is calculating more than 10 hours?

Comment: @James let me rephrase, "*...would also use the OS timer only, to calculate `10 hours`*".

Comment: Neither [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) nor [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx) will account for the time a system is hibernated. A [scheduled task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614.aspx) on the other hand, does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the basic plumbing underneath `Sleep()` and `SetTimer()` is the same.  Something you can see by calling `timeBeginPeriod()`, it affects the accuracy of both.  It is the clock tick interrupt handler that counts sleeps and timers down and gets the thread scheduled when it gets ready to run again.  Their sleep/wait time is adjusted when the system clock gets re-calibrated by a time server.

Comment: On Windows XP, when set to 1 milli-second mode (timeBeginPeriod(1), the ticker actually runs at 1024 hz, and during each 125 mill-second period, three double tick periods occur (at tick 42, 84, 125), using 128 internal ticks to result in a 125 ms period. A Sleep(1) can take up to almost 2 ms if on one of these double tick boundaries. I don't know about Windows Vista, but Windows 7 and later run at a true 1000 hz.